# find first row of dictionary inside view. First and FirstOrDefault throws error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a View where in I am binding dictionary.
Now I need to find first row of dictionary inside view. 
But if i use First or FirstOrDefault I am getting following errors.

System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary does not contain a definition for 'First'

'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault'

Please let me know how do i fetch 1st record of dictionary inside view.

Comment: have you tried .Select(x=>new KeyValuePair()).First()?

Comment: it says lamda expression not allowed

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question as i found solution:

In View dictionary is changed as an object so it is unable to recognize First Or FirstOrDefault extension methods.

So while checking again convert it as dictionary exclusively.

```
(new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>(row1 as System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>))
```